# Check Login, C++

Tags: c++

I am beginner with C++ so i started a Login/Register project to practice.
I've managed to code the Register part successfully, but i couldn't be able to check if the user entering the correct username and password, i've searched for a solution but i couldn't find any, so i would be grateful for any suggestions.

Here is the code:

```
void Login_System() {

    std::string login_id, login_username, login_password;
    std::fstream file;
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "      LOGIN        \n";
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";

    std::cout << "Enter your id: ";
    std::cin >> login_id;
    std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
    std::cin >> login_username;
    std::cout << "Enter your password: ";
    std::cin >> login_password;

        file.open("UsersInfo.txt", std::ios::in);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            std::string line;
            while (std::getline(file, line)) {
                

            }
        }
}

void Register_System() {

    std::fstream users_db;
    std::string register_username, register_id,register_password;
    system("cls");

    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "      REGISTER         \n";
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "Enter your ID: ";
    std::cin >> register_id;
    std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
    std::cin >> register_username;
    std::cout << "Enter your passowrd: ";
    std::cin >> register_password;

    users_db.open("UsersInfo.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (users_db.is_open()) {
        users_db << register_id << std::endl;
        users_db << register_username << std::endl;
        users_db << register_password << std::endl;
        users_db << std::endl;
        users_db << std::endl;
        users_db.close();
    }
    std::cout << "\nRegistration has been completed successfully\nPlease press any key to continue" << std::endl;
    system("pause>0");
    welcome_screen();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Note: you only need one `std::cout` for each continual block of text (not one per-line) Also, understand you never store passwords in files on disk. Instead you would hash the password and store the hash on disk and then for each login, you accept the password from the user, hash it and compare against the stored hash in the file. (I understand this is an exercise -- so just keep this in mind as you go forward) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:
Every account's info is saved at same line and id, name, password are divided by comma.
Each lines represent one account's information.
This code does not take the case where the ',' is included in id, username and password.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using AccountInfo = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;

void welcome_screen() {
    //. Your welcome code
}

void Login_System() {

    std::string login_id, login_username, login_password;
    std::fstream file;
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "      LOGIN        \n";
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";

    std::cout << "Enter your id: ";
    std::cin >> login_id;
    std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
    std::cin >> login_username;
    std::cout << "Enter your password: ";
    std::cin >> login_password;

    AccountInfo accounts;

    file.open("UsersInfo.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            std::string token;
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            std::vector<std::string> vec;
            while (std::getline(ss, token, ','))
            {
                vec.push_back(token);
            }
            accounts[vec[0]] = std::make_pair(vec[1], vec[2]);
        }
    }

    if (accounts.find(login_id) == accounts.end())
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Failed to login. There is no such user." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (accounts[login_id].first != login_username)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Invalid user name." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (accounts[login_id].second != login_password)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Invalid password." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Logged on successfully." << std::endl;
}

void Register_System() {

    std::fstream users_db;
    std::string register_username, register_id, register_password;
    system("cls");

    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "      REGISTER         \n";
    std::cout << "******************************************\n";
    std::cout << "Enter your ID: ";
    std::cin >> register_id;
    std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
    std::cin >> register_username;
    std::cout << "Enter your passowrd: ";
    std::cin >> register_password;

    users_db.open("UsersInfo.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (users_db.is_open()) {
        users_db << register_id << "," << register_username << "," << register_password << std::endl;
        users_db.close();
    }
    std::cout << "\nRegistration has been completed successfully\n" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    welcome_screen();
    system("cls");
}

int main()
{
    Register_System();
    Login_System();

    return 0;
}
```

But I think that it is not safe to save account's info as plain text. You must add encrypt/decrypt logic at save/load time.